# I'm having an Error in Mounted hook (Promise/Async) in my Vue js App

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, promise, vuex

ive setup my Vuex store and modules with all endpoints declared in my actions and connected to the getters too.

but my app returns this error compilation.

Help me check what might be wrong.

I have this in my methods

```
...mapActions('codes', [
      'fetchCode',
      'fetchCodes',
      'updateCode',
      'selectCode',
      'setSelectAllState'
  ]),

  async fetchData({page, sort}) {
    let data = {

      name: this.filters.name ? this.filters.name : null,

        from_date:
          this.filters.from_date === ''
            ? this.filters.from_date
            : this.filters.from_date,

        to_date:
          this.filters.to_date === ''
            ? this.filters.to_date
            : this.filters.to_date,

        orderByField: sort.fieldName || 'created_at',

        orderBy: sort.order || 'desc',
        page,
    }

    this.isRequestOngoing = true
    let response = await this.fetchCodes(data)
    this.isRequestOngoing = false

  

  return {
    
    data: response.data.result.data,

  }    
  },
```

It only returns this error in my browser console

> [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook (Promise/async): "TypeError: Cannot
> read properties of undefined (reading 'page')"

I've googled the hell out of this error, checked my api numerous times.. :(

Meanwhile the

```
  let response = await this.fetchCodes(data)
```

gets its data from this end (actions.js)

```
import * as types from './mutation-types'
export const fetchCodes = ({commit, dispatch, state}, params) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        window.axios
        .get(`/api/myendpoint`, {params})
        .then((response)=>{
            commit(types.FETCH_CODES, response.data.result.data)
            resolve(response)
        })
        .catch((err)=>{
            reject(err)
        })
    })
}
```

I've fixed the mutations to connect with their states too

Comment: It's unknown where and when actions are called. You say the problem is in the hook, but it's not shown. It's not shown where `page` is used. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . This `let response = await this.fetchCodes(data)` is wrong, actions don't return data they affect

Comment: Yeah, i'm actually not a vuejs developer per say. I only had to work on this app and this is the only seroious block i've experienced so far, ill update the question to make my question clearer.....

Comment: Obviously, you call `fetchData` w/o any arguments that's why JS can't destructure `page` from `undefined`. Check how you call ``fetchData and what arguments you pass there